# ListView doen'st update after updating throught App.OnResume()

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

In my ViewModel my update method perfectly workings when I'm updating directly from the ViewModel.
But if the method gets invoked by the OnResume() the ListView doesn'nt update beside the ProcessList gets correctly updatet.
Anybody an idea how to solve or on what other way I can assure that the list is updated permanently?

app.xaml.cs:

```
protected override async void OnResume()
{
    // Handle when your app resumes
    {
        await viewModel.UpdateProcessList();
    }
}
```

viewModel:

```
public async Task UpdateProcessList()
{
    if (IsBusy)
    {
        return;
    }

    IsBusy = true;
    await downloadService.DownloadProcessListAsync();
    LoadProcessList();
    IsBusy = false;
}

public void LoadProcessList()
{
    ProcessList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Process>>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(_fullFileNameProcessList));
    if (ProcessList != null)
    {
        ProcessList = ProcessList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like ProcessList is type List<SomeClass> ... So when you try to update it inside onResume it will not reflect/update listview... use observablecollection .... ObservableCollection<SomeClass> ProcessList {get;set;}

Comment: Have you tried doing this on MainThread? Since this is a Task which could mean it wouldn't reflect unless its on the UI thread

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have to call the NotifyPropertyChanged method in the end of UpdateProcessList task, except if you use an injector for that like 'fody'.